# Using the list of browsers from dropdown to run the application

Tags: c#, browser

I have a drop down list , in which i have list of browsers such as "Firefox,chrome,IE ", 
Now i want that when i run my application and select from the drop down the browser my application should run in that particular selected browser,can anyone help me in this as i have spend a lot of time searching on internet and haven't found any result so far. i am using c#.NET
thanks for your support.

Comment: is this a windows application launcher for a web application, windows forms and asp.net or what else? Do you understand that from the web application, once opened with the default browser or manually by the user even in a non default browser, your server side or client side code cannot (and should not) start a process like chrome or firefox in the client machine?

Comment: The question is a bit vague. Do you know that the end user has all of the browsers? If not then do you know which ones they do have? Do you know what the file path of these applications will be on the end user's computer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can look in the registry under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Clients\StartMenuInternet` to see the registered browsers that are installed (on my machine, IE, Firefox, Chrome and Opera all show up).

The default value under each browser's subkey is its name. Then you can look under the subkey `shell\open\command` to get the executable to run.

Here's some example code I wrote:

```
   private class Browser {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Exe { get; set; }
        public override string ToString() {
            return Name;
        }
    }

    private List<Browser> Browsers;

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        Browsers = new List<Browser>();
        const string browserListKey = @"SOFTWARE\Clients\StartMenuInternet";
        using (var clients = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(browserListKey)) {
            foreach (var client in clients.GetSubKeyNames()) {
                using (var clientKey = clients.OpenSubKey(client)) {
                    string name = (string)clientKey.GetValue(string.Empty);
                    using (var commandKey = clientKey.OpenSubKey(@"shell\open\command")) {
                        string exe = (string)commandKey.GetValue(string.Empty);
                        Browsers.Add(new Browser() { Name = name, Exe = exe });
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        comboBox1.DataSource = Browsers;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        string exe = ((Browser)comboBox1.SelectedItem).Exe;
        Process.Start(exe);
    }
```

Comment: guys this is a windows app  developing for internal usages for my firm, and regarding the end user thing,WE are the end users who would actually later be using this for testing purposes